# Error while converting timestamp string with timezone (+0000) to Timestamp using moment

Tags: node.js, datetime, momentjs, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to convert timestamp string `2021-09-29T05:32:48.000+0000` to time stamp using moment, but I am getting `NaN` as output. I am using this command to convert

`(moment("2021-09-29T05:32:48.000+0000"))`
Any suggestion on how I can handle the timestamp of this format in the node?

Comment: Can you show your complete code, seems to work fine with latest moment.js

Comment: The issue was something else, This timestamp was coming from the query string and the plus symbol was getting converted to space. so ```2021-09-29T05:32:48.000+0000``` becomes 
```2021-09-29T05:32:48.000 0000``` and moment was giving invalid date